# Why is this an unreachable statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, unreachable-statement

Towards the bottom of this code I am getting an "unreachable statement" error. I have tried a few things, but cannot figure out why this is happening. The error is towards the bottom of the code (I have commented with // where the error is) Please help point me in the right direction I'm stumped!

```
/**
* Describes a certain model.
* 
* @author (Joshua Baker) 
* @version (1.0)
*/
public class Model
{
public static final int IN_PER_FOOT = 12;
public static final int BASE_RATE = 60;
public static final int TALL_INCHES = 67;
public static final double THIN_POUNDS = 140.0;
public static final int TALL_THIN_BONUS = 5;
public static final int TRAVEL_BONUS = 4;
public static final int SMOKER_DEDUCTION = 10;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int heightInInches;
private double weightInPounds;
private boolean travel;
private boolean smokes;
private String newHeight;
private int perHourRate;

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public Model()
{
    setFirstName ("");
    setLastName  ("");
    setHeightInInches  (0);
    setWeightInPounds  (0.0);
    setTravel  (false);
    setSmokes  (false);
}

/**
 * 
 */
public Model (String whatIsFirstName, String whatIsLastName, int whatIsHeight, double whatIsWeight,
boolean canTravel, boolean smoker)
{
    setFirstName  (whatIsFirstName);
    setLastName  (whatIsLastName);
    setHeightInInches  (whatIsHeight);
    setWeightInPounds  (whatIsWeight);
    setTravel  (canTravel);
    setSmokes  (smoker);
}

/**
 *@return first name
 */
public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

/**
 *@return last name
 */
public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

/**
 *@return height in inches
 */
public int getHeightInInches()
{
    return heightInInches;
}

/**
 *@return the converted height 
 */
public String getNewHeight()
{
    return newHeight;
}

/**
 *@return weight in pounds
 */
public double getWeightInPounds()
{
    return weightInPounds;
}

/**
 *@return models pay per hour rate
 */
public int getPerHourRate()
{
    return perHourRate;
}


/**
 *@return travel
 */
public boolean getTravel()
{
    return travel;
}

/**
 *@return smokes
 */
public boolean getSmokes()
{
    return smokes;
}

/**
 * models first name
 */
public void setFirstName(String whatIsFirstName)
{
    firstName = whatIsFirstName;
}

 /**
 * models last name
 */
public void setLastName(String whatIsLastName)
{
    lastName = whatIsLastName;
}

 /**
 * models height in inches
 */
public void setHeightInInches(int whatIsHeight)
{
    if (whatIsHeight >0){
    heightInInches = whatIsHeight;
    }

}

 /**
 * models weight in pounds
 */
public void setWeightInPounds(double whatIsWeight)
{
    if (whatIsWeight >0){
    weightInPounds = whatIsWeight;
    }
}

 /**
 * can model travel
 */
public void setTravel(boolean canTravel)
{
    travel = canTravel;
}

 /**
 * does model smoke
 */
public void setSmokes(boolean smoker)
{
    smokes = smoker;
}

/**
 * Converts to feet and inches
 */
public String convertheightToFeetInches() 
{
int leftOver = (heightInInches %= IN_PER_FOOT);
int newHeight = (heightInInches % IN_PER_FOOT);
return newHeight + "Foot" + leftOver + "Inches";
}

/**
 * 
 */
public int calculatePayPerHour(){
    if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;
        return perHourRate;
    }
    else
    {
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
        return perHourRate;
    }

    if (travel)  {          //unreachable statement


        perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TRAVEL_BONUS;   
        return perHourRate;
    }
    else
    {
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
        return perHourRate;

    }

    if (smokes) {             //unreachable statement
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE - SMOKER_DEDUCTION;
        return perHourRate;
    }

    else {}

    }






/**
 * Displays details
 */
public  void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.print("Name : " + getFirstName() + " ");
    System.out.println(getLastName());
    System.out.println("Height : " + getNewHeight() + "inches");
    System.out.println("Weight : " + getWeightInPounds() + "pounds");
    System.out.print("Travel : " + getTravel() + " " );
    System.out.print("Smokes : " + getSmokes() );
    System.out.println("Hourly rate : " + getPerHourRate() );
}
```

}

Comment: Next time, please just add the code that has the issue.  This is a lot of code to scroll through to find a single comment buried in a single method.

Answer (score 11):

That is because your program will return from either your first `if block` or the corresponding `else` block: -

```
if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;
    return perHourRate;
}
else
{
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
    return perHourRate;
}
System.out.println("This will never get printed. And will show compiler error");
```

So, either of the two return statement will be executed. And hence any further code is unreachable.

---

Seems that you want to have cumulative sum of all the `service rates` to get the final `perHourRate`, for that, you can remove the `return statement` from each of the `if-else` block. And then for all the `if-else` block after the first one, instead of assigning the `current price` to `perHourRate`, do a `compound addition` `+=`.

Also, since you are working on the instance field - `perHourRate`, you don't need to return it at all. The changes you did on `perHourRate` can be obtained using `getPerHourRate()`. So, change the return type to `void`.

May you can try updating your `calculatePayPerHour` method to the one below:

```
public void calculatePayPerHour(){
    if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;  // Initial assignment

    } else {
        perHourRate = BASE_RATE;  // Initial assignment
    }

    /** Rest of the assignment will be compound assignment, since you
        are now updating the `perHourRate` **/

    if (travel)  {      
        perHourRate += TRAVEL_BONUS;   
    } // You don't need an else now. Since BASE_RATE is already added

    if (smokes) {    
        perHourRate -= SMOKER_DEDUCTION;
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense now! Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `calculatePayPerHour` method you have an if/else and the statement will never be reached because in both cases you are returning a result:

```
if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;
    return perHourRate; // you return in the if
}
else
{
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
    return perHourRate; // you return in the else
}

... the execution will never reach here
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;
    return perHourRate; // <------------
}
else
{
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
    return perHourRate;  // <------------
}
```

Regardless of your height or weight, one of these 2 returns will trigger, so any statement after it will never be executed. This is identical to the below code.

```
if (heightInInches  >= TALL_INCHES && (weightInPounds <= THIN_POUNDS)) {
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE + TALL_THIN_BONUS;
}
else
{
    perHourRate = BASE_RATE;
}

return perHourRate;  
//unreachable
```

Answer (score 2):

in the if/else above the code you have 2 return statements already...
This means it will never reach the code below this..

Answer (score 2):

- In your method `public int calculatePayPerHour()` the first if else statement is returning a value in any case (in both if and else block).
- If you dry run the program you will see that the **control flow** will never reach statements below this block hence your exception.